# Create tables in hive from ddl files

Tags: jdbc, hive, ddl

I am using JRuby to connect to Hive, which is happening successfully. Now I want to create tables, but instead of writing the create statement as a parameter to execute() method, I want to call a ddl file that has the table definition.

I cannot take the file contents and use them because they are usually more than one statement before the actual table creation (i.e. CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS, CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ..)

Is there a command that I can use through my JDBC connect that take the ddl file and executes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge there is no direct way  with JDBC API to do an operation similar to hive -f , 
option 1) 
you can parse your SQL file and write a method to execute the commands sequentially (or) use third party code,

here is one reference  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/802383/Run-SQL-Script-sql-containing-DDL-DML-SELECT-state

option 2) If your client environment where Jruby code is running also supports hive, write a shell script which can connect to remote JDBC and run SQL with beeline which will make remote Thrift calls

Reference : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients